# How to terminate map.on() function for Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I used the Mapbox JS API for showing coordinates. This is the link of the document: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mouse-position/

I have two buttons. After I click the first one, when the mouse is hovering the map, it shows the coordinates.

What I want to do is that after I click the second button, the previous running function can terminate. Can you help me on that?

```
function showCor() {
        map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
            document.getElementById('coord-info-lat').innerHTML =
                JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.lat.toFixed(5));

            document.getElementById('coord-info-lng').innerHTML =
                JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.lng.toFixed(5));
        });

}

function notShowCor() {
// Please help me here.
}
```

Comment: There is off method - https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#off - which "removes an event listener previously added with Map#on".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting an 'isActive' flag. Here is my code.

```
let isActive = true;

//function to show the position
function showCor() {
    isActive = true;
    map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (isActive) {
            document.getElementById('coord-info-lat').innerHTML =   
                JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.lat.toFixed(5));
            document.getElementById('coord-info-lng').innerHTML =
                JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.lng.toFixed(5));
        }

    });

}

//function to clear the info and terminate the function.
function notShowCor() {
    isActive = false;
    document.getElementById('coord-info-lat').innerHTML = 'N/A';
    document.getElementById('coord-info-lng').innerHTML = 'N/A';
}
```

Please advise if you have better solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately i can think of 2 options that might help you;

1.Change the html to equal ""

```
function notShowCor() {
 map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
            document.getElementById('coord-info-lat').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('coord-info-lng').innerHTML = "";
        });
}
```

2. Set both elements to have opacity 0 (Though it would technically still be running)
   Assuming you had CSS styles as follows:

```
#coord-info-lat, #coord-info-lng {
   opacity:0;
}
#coord-info-lat.shown, coord-info-lng.shown {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```
function showCor() {
        map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
            var lat = document.getElementById('coord-info-lat');
            var lng = document.getElementById('coord-info-lng');
            lat.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.lat.toFixed(5));
            lng.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.lng.toFixed(5));

            lat.className = "shown";
            lng.className = "shown";
        });
}

function notShowCor() { 
        document.getElementById('coord-info-lat').className = "";
        document.getElementById('coord-info-lng').className = "";
}
```

You could also do a combination of the 2