# mapbox start stop behaviour instead of onload

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Mapbox has lots of examples, where features are loaded in the beginning and then are available forever. T.e. the measurement example:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/measure/.

The example codes usually use

```
  map.on('load', function () {
```

This permanent availability is not what I need. I'm building an application, where such features should be started by a button and stopped by a second button like this:

```
  <div class='button' onclick='startMeasuring();'>Start measuring</div>
  <div class='button' onclick='stopMeasuring();'>Stop measuring</div>
```

How do I have to change the code in the mapbox example to accomplish this?
Preferrably I'd like to generate a Class "MyTools" in which startMeasuring() and all the other features are just methods.

New added main problem - running onclicks in parallel:

```
        map.on('click', function (e) {
          [.. do task 1 ..]
        }  
        map.on('click', function (e) {
          [.. do task 2 ..]
        }  
        map.on('click', function (e) {
          [.. do task 3 ..]
        }
```

Now how can I stop selectivley the click running task 2 ?

Comment: Check [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-a-line/)... it includes a start/pause button drawing a line. Convert that to classes is a dev implementation detail, surely you can manage that

Comment: Not really useful, because pausing causes resuming the drawing at the stopped position. I'm targeting a full reset of the function with a reset/redefine of all starting parameters.

Comment: Not clear for me what's the point you're stuck on... what's the code you have implemented so far? if you add a minimal reproducible example it'll be easier to help you

Comment: Meanwhile I could reduce my problem to the stop function. When using multiple examples from mapbox you get lots of (anonymous?) onclick functions working in parallel. Some I want, others I want to stop. Now how can I selectively stop one of them? See the new code I've added to above mastertext.

Comment: You only need one `map.on(‘click’` to capture all the clicks, the key pressed is in the args received by the event as params. I would implement whatever the logic you are trying to do in that way

Comment: Your concept is surely smart for starting multiple onclicks. But still: I want an outside button to stop/cancel just one out of it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This guy has a very similar problem which I consider not be solved in a clean way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56031532/how-to-terminate-map-on-function-for-mapbox?rq=1

Comment: I added for you an answer to this last problem. As said without more code and a reproducible example is quite hard to help you

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to cancel completely the event handler (detach the event), then you have to use [`map.off("click"), ...`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/events/#evented#off) this is their implementation of `DetachEventHandler`

```js
map.off('click', function(e) {
  // this will detach the click event handling 
  console.log('Detached');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to work with more compact examples: 
function pickCoords()  {
 console.log("pickCoords():");
 map.on('click', function (e) {
   w = JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.wrap());    ... works fine } 
but all exercises to stop don't work:  

function pickCoordsCancel()  {
 console.log("pickCoordsCancel():");
 map.off('click');
 //map.on('click', function (e) {});
 //map.off('click', function (e) {});
 //map.off('click', onClick);
 //map.off('click', 'onClick');
};

Comment: If you provide a minimal reproducible example on a fiddle or codepen , I'll take a look to it, otherwise sorry but in this format is almost impossible to help you. Good luck